# Determine the formula for hexagon arrangements.

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, combinatorial-geometry

The puzzle to be solved is similar to a jigsaw but using n regular hexagons of equal size for pieces. The pieces are to be placed within a defined perimeter to create a picture.

**Q:** If we let the number of pieces be n, and the number of possible different placements be P, determine a mathematical expression for P in terms of n using logical arguments related to selection and rotation.

HINT: When n=4, P=31104

The answer I have come up with is `P(n) = (n!)(6^n)`

I used `n!` due to the puzzle being a combination problem (the selection). I used `6^n` based upon the possible rotations of each hexagon.

Is this correct?

Thank you! :D